# Skipping over iterator values in a Table

Tags: programming, list-manipulation, iterators

I have been using the built-in function `Table` for some computations. (The following is not an actual representation of the equations I am using).

$$\text{Table}[f[k]=g[k],\{k,1,10\}]$$

However, the assignment $f[k]=g[k]$ is not true for one $k$ value, say $k=6$. That is, say, $g[k]=k^2+1$ for $k\neq 6$ and $g[6]=1$ (when $k=6$).

I can then break the table into two parts: $\{k,1,5\}$ and $\{k,7,10\}$.

Is there any other (more efficient) way of doing this?

Comment: Please do not use LaTeX to format code.  It makes it impossible to copy and paste it.  Use a proper code box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this without `Table`:

```
g[k_] := k^2 + 1

Map[If[# != 6, f[#] = g[#], f[#] = 1] &, Range[10]]
```

> {2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 1, 50, 65, 82, 101}

You can also use `Scan` in place of `Map` (it may be slightly faster for large lists). Note that no result will be displayed, but `f` will still retain the values stored in it.

```
Scan[If[# != 6, f[#] = g[#], f[#] = 1] &, Range[10]]
```

You can retrieve the values as follows:

```
f /@ Range[10]
```

> {2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 1, 50, 65, 82, 101}

Comment: Dear @RunnyKine, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Radz You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to RunnyKine's recommendation of `If` here are two other methods to consider.

#### 1: Unset or restore the value

Simply [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html) `f[6]` afterward:

```
Do[f[k] = g[k], {k, 10}];
f[6] =.

Array[f, 10]
```

> ```
> {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5], f[6], g[7], g[8], g[9], g[10]}
> ```

Note `f[6]` is returned as it is undefined.

Or if `f[6]` already has a value save and restore it:

```
f[k_] := 9 k

k6 = f[6];
Do[f[k] = g[k], {k, 10}];
f[6] = k6;

Array[f, 10]
```

> ```
>  {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5], 54, g[7], g[8], g[9], g[10]}
> ```

#### 2: [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Delete.html) the value from your iterator range

```
Do[f[k] = g[k], {k, Range[10] ~Delete~ 6}];

Array[f, 10]
```

> ```
> {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5], f[6], g[7], g[8], g[9], g[10]}
> ```

Again note `f[6]` is returned in the output.

Comment: Dear @Mr.Wizard, Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can use the `If` also inside the table:

```
Table[If[k != 6, f[k] = g[k], f[k] = 1], {k, 10}]
```

You can also use the `If` on the right hand side of the assignment:

```
Table[f[k] = If[k != 6, g[k], 1], {k, 10}]
```

If the whole purpose of the table is the assignment, that is you are not really interested in the list it outputs, you can replace `Table` with [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) (I imagine that would also be faster, but I haven't measured it):

```
Do[If[k != 6, f[k] = g[k], f[k] = 1], {k, 10}]
```

Another option (which especially is useful if the two ranges are far apart and you don't need to assign to intermediate values of `f`) is to build the iterator from the two subranges explicitly:

```
Do[f[k] = g[k], {k, Range[5] ~Join~ Range[7,10]}]
```

Yet another option would be to use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html):

```
Table[f[k]=Piecewise[{{g[k], k!=6}}, 1], {k, 10}]
```

Comment: Dear @celtschk, Thank you for you help.

Comment: @Radz: You're welcome.